# How can I get the database schema of a EdmType

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Given an instance of EdmType, how do I get the database schema of the corresponding table?

I could find a property for the table name (of course), but nothing for the schema.

I looked at the properties and meta data. Nothing.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EdmType` doesn't contain such information. You need instance of `EntitySet` from  `System.Data.Metadata.Edm` namespace and search its `MetadataProperties` collection for `MetadataItem` with `Name == "Schema"`. The `Value` property of this item will contain database schema.

Comment: I'm getting null from ObjectStateManager's EntityEntry using  entry.EntitySet.MetadataProperties.First(p => p.Name == "Schema").Value using EF 4.3.1